# Is there any way to get an alert when an Azure App registration secret has been expired?

Tags: azure

My Client Secret for an app registration is expired but there is no notification regarding it from azure side. need a solution to get notified when an secret is expired

I have seen some solutions but and need help regarding it

Comment: Hi Rakesh whats do you need to know can you elaborate and be more specific in asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to get an alert when an Azure App registration secret has been expired?

There is way to create an alert when an `Azure App registration` secret has been expired using `logic app`.

1. Create an `Azure App` registration with secrets

[image]

2. Create a **Logic App**

[image]

3. Setup the `Logic Apps` flow by navigating the below steps **Logic App > Workflows > Add  > Select the Workflows > Designer > Create a design**

[image]

**Logic app design**

[image]

Follow the [document](https://www.inthecloud247.com/get-notified-on-expiring-azure-app-registration-client-secrets/) created by **Peter** to follow the `Logic Apps` flow to trigger the email when **azure app registration** secret has been expired.